# How should I read or interpret this notation?

Tags: optimization, notation, propositional-calculus

Context: A.E. Prieditis 1993, where the length of shortest path from states was getting discussed and saw below formula for same.

I can make the min and sigma notation but the |,= and ^ are not making sense to me. I mean I know what typically they are used for like denoting OR and disjunction.

[image: formula]

[P.F.A formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgNXi.png)

Comment: Very bad noattions but I would treat $s_1=s$ and $s_n =t$ as separate conditions. The third condition in the middle would then be clear.

Comment: We write $\{x\mid P(x)\}$ to mean "the set of all those $x$ which satisfy $P(x)$". So you are taking the min of a whole slew of function values where we have $s_1=s$, $s_n=t$ and every $s_i$ lies in $S$. [I think the question will be closed, so I won't answer.]

Comment: thanks guys! not crystal clear but does make relatively more sense now.

Comment: There is just a $\land$ missing between $s_1=s$ and $\bigwedge_\limits{1\le i\le n}s_i\in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unnecessarily complicated notation.
The intention is simple & can be stated in simpler terms too.

Intention is that $k(s,t)$ is the minimum of the summation where each transition from state to state has some cost.
There are $n-1$ such transitions &  $n-1$ associated costs.
We want the transitions to start with $s$ & terminate with $t$.

The unnecessarily completed part is after the $|$ , which just says that :
$s_1=s$ [ Starting State ] AND
$s_i \in S$ [ all states are in Universal Set $S$ ] AND
$s_n=t$ [ Terminal State ]

The middle condition is to cover all States.
Simpler to write it like these variations :
$\forall i : s_i \in S$
$s_i \in S , \forall i$
$s_i \in S$ for all $i$
$s_i \in S , 1 \le i \le n$
$s_i \in S , i \in [1,\cdots,n]$

When we try all ways to start with $s$ & terminate with $t$ , then we will have multiple Paths. We want to choose the minimum cost Path. Here $k(s,t)$ is the minimum cost of that Set of Paths.
The actual Path is not given by this formula.